# how can we say visualforce is a frame work?

Tags: visualforce

I have a doubt from the date when I stared learning the visualforce.

How can we say the visualforce is a framework? The VF page is having start and end tag how JQuery,XML and Java script have. But we are calling the Java script is script language. VF is a not also markup language.

Why we can not call it as a markup language also?

Please explain me.

Answer (score 2):

> What is FrameWork?

In computer programming, a software **framework is an abstraction** in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing **application-specific software**. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)

> What is Markup language?

A markup language is a computer language **that uses tags** to define elements within a document. It is human-readable, meaning markup files contain standard words, rather than typical programming syntax. While several markup languages exist, the two most popular are HTML and XML. [Source](https://techterms.com/definition/markup_language)

> From Visualforce Doc:

Visualforce is the **component-based user interface framework** for the Force.com platform. The framework includes a **tag-based markup language**, similar to HTML. Each Visualforce tag corresponds to a coarse or fine-grained user interface component, such as a section of a page, or a field. [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce)

If you ever get the chance to work upon JSP (java server pages), you would know it has taglib directive by which you can create your own custom tags. So it looks like(although i am not 100% sure) that Visualforce is written over JSP utilizing its custom tag creation functionality thus it is a framework and a tag based markup language.